# railsでpramsの値によるURL指定について

Tags: ruby-on-rails

railsで家計簿アプリを作成しているのですが、トップページで選択した
年、月をURLとして渡したいと思っております。

paramsの値を反映させることがうまくいかないのですが、
何か良い方法があればご教授頂けませんでしょうか。

◾️やりたいこと
formの「開く」を押したときに
`http://localhost:3000/book/202008`　などのURLで個別の家計簿を開くようにしたい。

◾️現状
formの「開く」を押すと
`http://localhost:3000/book/:selectYear`　となる。
※paramsの値がURLに指定できてでいない。

◾️試したこと
ルーティングの設定、resoucesなども使ってみましたが、よくわからなくなってしましました。。

◾️トップページのフォームビュー部分

```
.main_select
      家計簿を選択する
      = form_with method: 'post', url: 'book/:selectYear' , local: true do |form|
        .choice_field
          = form.select :selectYear, @year
          = form.select :selectMonth, @month
          月家計簿
          .br
          = form.submit :開く
```

◾️現状のルーティング

```
get '/', to:'book#index'
post 'book/:selectYear', to: 'book#edit'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

下記のように記載してURLに指定ではないですが、paramsの値として渡すことで何とかなりました。

```
.main_select
      家計簿を選択する
      = form_with method: 'get', url: '/edit' , local: true do |form|
        .choice_field
          = form.select :selectYear, @year,{id:"test"}
          = form.select :selectMonth, @month
          .br
          = form.submit :開く
```